# Trying to control the user's input to strictly a positive number only

Tags: python, if-statement, exception

I am trying to control the user's input using exception handling. I need them to only input a positive number, and then I have to return and print out that number.
I have to send a message if the user puts in non-number and I have to send a message if the user puts in a number less than 1. Here is what I have:

```
def input_validation(prompt):
    boolChoice = True
    while boolChoice == True:
        try:
            l = input(prompt)
            x = int(l)
            boolChoice = False
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid input")
            if l.isalpha() == True:
                print("Your input is not a number")
            elif l.isalnum() == True:
                print ("Your input is not completely a positive number")
            elif l < 0:
                print("Your number is not positive")
            print("Try again")
    return x

def main():
    x = input_validation("Enter a positive number: ")
    print (x)
main()
```

My program works fine until a negative integer gets inputted. It doesn't print the message and then goes through the loop again, it just returns and prints back the negative number, which I don't want. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: A negative number is not going to cause an exception, so it's pointless to check for it in the `except` clause.  You'll need to put it in the `try` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try...except` to check if its an integer or letters

```
def input_validation(prompt):
    
    while True:
        try:
            l = int(input(prompt))
            if l<0: #=== If value of l is < 0 like -1,-2
                print("Not a positive number.")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Your input is invalid.")
            print("Try again")
    return l

def main():
    x = input_validation("Enter a positive number: ")
    print (x)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def input_validation(prompt):
    boolChoice = True
    while boolChoice == True:
        try:
            l = input(prompt)
            x = int(l)
            if x < 0:
                print ("Your input is a negative number\n Please enter a postive number")
            elif x == 0:
                print("Your input is zero\n Please enter a postive number ")
            else:
                boolChoice = False 
        except Exception as e:
            print("Not a valid input")
            if l.isalpha() == True:
                print("Your input is not a number")
            elif l.isalnum() == True:
                print ("Your input is not completely a positive number")
            else:
                print(f"Failed to accept input due to {e}")
            print("Try again")
            continue
    return x

def main():
    x = input_validation("Enter a positive number: ")
    print (x)
main()
```

Comment: hello, thank you. Is there a built in function to check if the input is a negative number with a letter? similar to the l.isalnum, but to see if there are negative numbers. because if I input like -5t, it gives an error. thank you

Comment: there is no inbuilt function to identify if a number is negative, however you can catch the exception for inputs like -5t and continue with the loop until it receives a valid input. I have updated the above code to handle the same

Comment: @jay could you mark the answer as accepted if it helped.

Comment: hi, how do I do that? thank you for the help

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work